# Why I cannot compre the expression and null directly in C#?

Tags: c#

```
        cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        ...
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 0)
            goto doClose;
        else
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // this is line 182, check the exception details below
```

**More**:
I have to go to bed. And here below is the code source (my repo from GitHub), if anyone could take a look at it?
git@github.com:tomxuetoy/WPF_startPrograms.git

Above is my code and it can work normally. In my case `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` will return null due to the `SQLite` table doesn't exist.
And I tried to change it like below but failed:

```
if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
```

So I want to know why I cannot compre the expression(`null` returned) and `null` directly?
Thanks!

**More**:
Below ones are tried but with the same result: cannot work

```
if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value)
or
if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() is DBNull)
```

The exception detailed is copied below, but with some Chinese characters...

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=对类型“MultiStart.MainWindow”的构造函数执行符合指定的绑定约束的调用时引发了异常。
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  StackTrace:
       在 System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=SQLite error
no such table: testTable
       Source=System.Data.SQLite
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       StackTrace:
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            在 System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader()
            在 MultiStart.MainWindow.dbOp(dowhat dw) 位置 c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WPF_startPrograms\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs:行号 182
            在 MultiStart.MainWindow.DataBinding() 位置 c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WPF_startPrograms\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs:行号 43
            在 MultiStart.MainWindow..ctor() 位置 c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WPF_startPrograms\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs:行号 36
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Is that a `goto` statement?

Comment: You can. What's not working?

Comment: If you're going to say that something you've tried didn't work, *always* give more details.

Comment: Yes, that is a goto, but it may not be the key for my question.

Comment: try like this `if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() is DBNull)`

Comment: @user1671639 I don't think `ExecuteScalar` returns `DBNull` when no result. It returns `null`. I don't know about `SqlLite` implementation though

Comment: You get an exception, not null... use a `try { } catch ( SQLiteException exp) { DoSomethingWithIt(exp) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to do it is check if the table exists first. One of the ways to do it is call [`DbConnection.GetSchema(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53he2tz.aspx) passing in whatever argument SqLite uses for its tables schema.

I don't have a SqLite database to test with but it would be something like this

```
var tableName = "testTable";
var commandText = "Select * from " + tableName;

using(var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    var schema = conn.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, null, tableName });
    if(schema.Rows.Count == 0) //I am assuming your original ExecuteScalar query was some kind of "If Exists" query to test for the table.
        return;

    using(var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, conn))
    {
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
              //....
        }
    }
}
```

If the name of the schema that lists all available tables is not `Tables` just call `conn.GetSchema()` with no arguments to see all of the available choices of schemas.

Comment: var schema = conn.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, null, "testTable" });
                if (schema.Rows.Count == 0)
                    return 1;   // this way it works

Answer (score 1):

You don't get that far that a null value is returned. Before it does the `Reader`(and/or the `ExecuteScalar`) throws an exception at you. Catch it and handle accordingly...

```
try 
{
       if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 0)
            goto doClose; // Really? That must be complex then...
        else
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
}
catch(SQLiteException exp)
{
       Trace.WriteLine( exp.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IDbCommand.ExecuteScalar is the underlying interface method. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this method:

"If the first column of the first row in the result set is not found, a null reference (**Nothing** in Visual Basic) is returned. If the value in the database is **null**, the query returns **DBNull.Value**".

Your code should handle either case.

However... if the table specified in your query doesn't exist, you'll get an exception thrown, just as you would for any other failure case (syntax error in your query, etc.). You should wrap **all** of your database interactions with try/catch logic; there are failure cases for pretty much anything you might do against a database, and all failure cases are communicated to your application code by throwing an exception.

```
try
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result == null)
    {
        // handle null case
    }
    else if (result is DbNull)
    {
        // handle DbNull case
    }
    else
    {
        // usable result you can cast as appropriate
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle all other eventualities
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here :-

1. How to handle exception on ExecuteScalar If table does not exist.
2. How to probably close the connection/command (without using the GoTo
   statement)

For 1), I don't quite agree on checking on schema first. You should really put this Db operation in a function and then wrap function in a try/catch and handle in a standard way (error reporting /logs etc)

For 2) If you expect, your query to return either 1 or many rows, why use ExecuteScalar at all? Why not just use ExecuteReader() to retrieve one or many rows. Also, wrap the reader in a "using" block that would make sure of closing connections/reader.